# Gulp LiveReload is not working with Electron

Tags: typescript, gulp, electron, livereload

I have an Electron app with Typescript. The structure of my project is as follows:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWunz.png)

In /src is my code allocated, and in /www is where my compiled (transpiled, in fact) code is allocated.

I made a toy exercice with gulp-livereload based on this example:
[Live reload for electron application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445766/live-reload-for-electron-application)

And it works fine! But in my project is not the case.

In my index.html I have the following line added:

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

And this is my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task("sass", function() {
return gulp.src(paths.sass)
    .pipe(sass())
    .on("error", sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(outDir))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({
        compatibility: "ie8"
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
        extname: ".min.css"
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(outDir))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task("watch", ["compile"], function() {
livereload.listen();    
gulp.watch(["./src/**/*.scss", "./src/**/*.ts", "!./src/lib/**"], ["clean-min-sources"]);
gulp.watch(["./src/**/*", "!./src/**/*.ts", "!./src/**/*.scss"], ["copy-assets"]);
gulp.watch(["./src/**/*.*"]);    
});
```

What's the difference between my project and my example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got it! I I forgot to put the task in gulp.wach: `gulp.watch(paths.allFiles, ["compile"]);`